# SMPlayer and Gnome Player (mplayer in fact) cannot play (crash imediatly) in Lubuntu  . What can I do?

Tags: lubuntu, mplayer, smplayer

I have just reinstalled my Lubuntu OS.

I have installed lubuntu and ubuntu-restricted extras but cannot play video in  smplayer or gnome player.

log shows something like:

```
/usr/bin/mplayer -noquiet -nofs -nomouseinput -sub-fuzziness 1
-identify -slave -vo xv, -nokeepaspect -framedrop -nodr -double -input conf=/usr/share/smplayer/input.conf -stop-xscreensaver -wid 50331689
 -monitorpixelaspect 1 -ass -embeddedfonts -ass-line-spacing 0 -ass-font-scale 1 -ass-styles /home/cprq/.config/smplayer/styles.ass -fontconfig -font Arial -subfont-autoscale 0 -subfont-osd-scale 20 -subfont-text-scale 20 -subcp ISO-8859-1 -subpos 100 -nocache -osdlevel 0 -vf-add screenshot -slices -channels 2 -af equalizer=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 -softvol -softvol-max 110
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot"? Can you explain what actually happens.

Comment: just says `Mplayer has crashed. See the log for mor info.` And the log is like above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you experience is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mplayer2/+bug/976465). Lubuntu has `mplayer2` installed by default, which is a fork of mplayer. Try removing `mplayer2` and installing 'mplayer` instead, in other words, something like the following.

```
sudo apt-get purge mplayer2 && sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get install mplayer gecko-mediaplayer gnome-mplayer
```

Comment: that was it, now it's ok. is there something to avoid this? maybe just installing smplayer2 instead? in the past i used mplayer2 with smplayer and gnome player with no problems

Comment: Not sure about avoiding. I've stumbled over it in May when testing Lubuntu, and the bug is, apparently, not fixed yet. The problem seems to be with the backend, in other words, mplayer2 rather then smplayer.